# Android Emulator connecting to Local Web service

Tags: java, android, service

Hi all I have a local web service set up on my machine, it is a web service which was built in netbeans using the JPA. I have it connecting locally to a mySQL server also. I have both the database and web service connecting. The webservice can display XML/JSON. My problem is getting the android emulator to consume the JSON from the web service.  The URL we are using is "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Web4/resources/hotel2s/" this should allow the emulator to connect to the web service am I correct? When I try to launch and consume the emulator crashes. Here is some source code. We are sure that it should read in and parse with GSON etc but we are not sure if it is connecting or not.

**RESULT CLASS**

```
public class hotel_Result 
{
    @SerializedName("hotelAddress")
    protected String hotelAddress;
    @SerializedName("HotelDescription")
    protected String hotelDescription;
    @SerializedName("hotelName")
    protected String hotelName;
    @SerializedName("hotelRating")
    protected int hotelRating;
}
```

**HOTEL RESPONSE CLASS**

```
public class hotel_Response
{
public List<hotel_Result> hotelresults;
public String query;
}
```

**MAIN CLASS**

```
public class connectRest extends Activity 

{
    // We tried Reg's machines ip here as well and it crashed also used different ips is this correct for the emulator to connect to it?
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Web4/resources/hotel2s/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        InputStream source = retrieveStream(url); // Stream in the URL

        Gson gson = new Gson(); // GSON object

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source); // Read in the stream

        hotel_Response response = gson.fromJson(reader,hotel_Response.class); // Fill in the variables in the class hotel_response

        Toast.makeText(this,response.query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        List<hotel_Result> hotelresults = response.hotelresults;


        for(hotel_Result hotel_Result : hotelresults)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,hotel_Result.hotelName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }   

    private InputStream retrieveStream(String url)
    {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try{
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Error" + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Error for URL " + url, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the logcat,so that the reason behind the crash can be identified

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the allow internet access permission in your manifest.

Here's a better try-catch implementation and it does the work in an AsyncTask() to keep the UI thread happy :)  The original article can be found on Java Code Geeks (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) but it lacks my improvements!

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.javacodegeeks.android.json.model.Result;
import com.javacodegeeks.android.json.model.SearchResponse;

public class JsonParsingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=javacodegeeks";
    protected InitTask _initTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _initTask = new InitTask();
                _initTask.execute( getApplicationContext() );
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        _initTask.cancel(true);
    }

    protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, SearchResponse>
    {
        @Override
        protected SearchResponse doInBackground( Context... params ) 
        {
            InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
            SearchResponse response = null;
            if (source != null) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
                try {
                    response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
                    publishProgress( response.query );
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage() + " for URL " + url);
                }
            }
            if (!this.isCancelled()) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s) 
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( SearchResponse response ) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            if (response != null) {
                String delim = "* ";
                List<Result> results = response.results;
                for (Result result : results) {
                    builder.append(delim).append(result.fromUser);
                    delim="\n* ";
                }
            }
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The response was empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The operation was cancelled.", 1).show();
        }

        private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpGet getRequest;
            try {
                getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                return getResponseEntity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have that included :) but since its a local host does it have to reach the internet?

Comment: Your call to HTTP is what dictates that permission (I think).

Comment: I believe you :) but I do have it added to my manifest. As I mentioned in my question the REST webservice was built in net beans using the JPA, when I take the link at the top and put it into my broswer it asks me to download .json file. Should it not just open and display? could does be a propblem?

Comment: I implemented the GSON/JSON example posted at Java Code Geeks to consume a JSON web service.  Looks strikingly similar to what you have there ;)  Try setting a break point on your InputStream source line.  Then step over each line until you figure out which piece is breaking.  Then repeat but step into the broken function.  You'll eventually narrow it down.  I'll edit my response to include my modified implementation of their code.  I have a simplified try-catch that will write an error to the log, but it catches more than they did in their example.

Comment: Almost certainly is the problem.  It should display the JSON string in your browser.

Comment: Okay so that narrows it down to the URL being a problem. With netbeans its very bad for displaying what you want we had to change the code that was auto generated from the JPA to not display XML and just JSON. We always get a download .json file but never the JSON displayed. When the file is downloaded it is well formed JSON alright.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full try-catch implementation of the code above.  I implemented this first and then realized all I really needed to know was pass/fail.  Anyway, might help someone.  Again, props go to Java Code Geeks for getting me started ... [Android JSON Parsing with GSON Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.javacodegeeks.android.json.model.Result;
import com.javacodegeeks.android.json.model.SearchResponse;

public class JsonParsingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=javacodegeeks";
    protected InitTask _initTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _initTask = new InitTask();
                _initTask.execute( getApplicationContext() );
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        _initTask.cancel(true);
    }

    protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, SearchResponse>
    {
        @Override
        protected SearchResponse doInBackground( Context... params ) 
        {
            InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
            SearchResponse response = null;
            if (source != null) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
                try {
                    response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
                    publishProgress( response.query );
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage() + " for URL " + url); 
                    return null;
                } catch (JsonIOException e) {
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage() + " for URL " + url);
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage() + " for URL " + url);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!this.isCancelled()) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s) 
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( SearchResponse response ) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            if (response != null) {
                String delim = "* ";
                List<Result> results = response.results;
                for (Result result : results) {
                    builder.append(delim).append(result.fromUser);
                    delim="\n* ";
                }
            }
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The response was empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The operation was cancelled.", 1).show();
        }

        private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpGet getRequest;
            try {
                getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
                    final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
                        return null;
                    }
                    HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                    try {
                        return getResponseEntity.getContent();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        getRequest.abort();
                        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
                        return null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        getRequest.abort();
                        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    getRequest.abort();
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    getRequest.abort();
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Okay so that narrows it down to the URL being a problem. With netbeans its very bad for displaying what you want we had to change the code that was auto generated from the JPA to not display XML and just JSON. We always get a download .json file but never the JSON displayed. When the file is downloaded it is well formed JSON alright

Comment: Okay I tested it and added the internet permissions  works fine :) nice code :) I think the problem I am facing now is figuring out what my URL should be to get JSON to display in the browser do you agree?

Comment: Change their URL with yours.  It will catch the error and tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: We will try Bill. Try to understand we have tried all the URLs possible. Netbean sucks for it. If we were to host the web service on a site would that help? We tried the following URLS http://localhost:8080/Web4/resources/hotel2s/ http://localhost:8080/Web4/resources/hotel2s/ http://10.0.2.2:8080/Web4/application.wadl) http://myping:8080/Web4/resources/hotel2s/ http://10.0.2.2:8080/Web4/resources/application.wadl http://127.0.0.1:8080/Web4/resources/application.wadl  All of these we have tried with no luck. I don't know what netbeans uses to be accessed.

Comment: Also when we store the URL in a string we append the end of it with a ?hotelName=Clarion Hotel

Comment: That sucks.  I've seen a couple of your other posts.  Recognize the "Clarion Hotel" and web service reference now.  Here's my URL: http://aws.aydabtudev.com/BroadcastSMSLite.json

Comment: Yeah see netbeans never gives you a .json URL like that.. jsut a .wadl at the top of the thing Web service were you can test it.. Ideas?

Comment: Sorry.  I wish I could help more.